# Cucumber-JVM: Call a Scenario or ScenarioOutline inside a step definition

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a step definition where I pass the name of a Scenario or Scenario outline:

```
@When("^I execute the steps of the following scenario or scenario outline: \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void execute_steps_of_the_scenario_or_scenario_outline(String name){
...
}
```

My intent is to execute all the steps of the called Scenario/ScenarioOutline, and append those executed steps to the current scenario. This means that the steps of the called scenario become a part of the current scenarion.

However I have been unable to figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber (and BDD/TDD in general) are not meant to be used like that. Each scenario/test should be isolated from each other and is not a good practice to executes steps from one scenario on another.

You can use Background steps on a feature to execute common steps across the scenarios of that feature or you can also use tags to execute a particular set of actions before and/or after a scenario is executed using Hooks.

Having said that, you could write some logic in your glue code to maintain a list of steps (methods) which are invoked in each scenario and invoke the same list of steps on a subsequent scenario. This assumes that you could guarantee the execution order of the scenarios, which is (again) against all TDD best practices. Below is an example of the skeleton code to achieve what I have just described.

```
private Scenario scenario;

private Map<String, List<String>> scenarioSteps = new HashMap<>();

@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {

    this.scenario = scenario;

    scenarioSteps.put(scenario.getName(), new LinkedList<>());
}

@Given("^the first step is executed$")
public void the_first_step_is_executed() {

    final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];

    scenarioSteps.get(scenario.getName()).add(stackTraceElement.getClassName() + "." + stackTraceElement.getMethodName());
}
```

Comment: How would I execute the step in your code after I've added it to "scenarioSteps"? If the glue code of the step requires an argument/parameter, then how would I be able to reuse the define parameters from the scenario I took the step from?

Comment: You would need to maintain a more complex list of objects for the steps associated with a scenario. You could for example main a list of a custom "Step" object which would have as attributes the class.method associated with the step and a Map<String,Object> with the required params for that step.